# PowerShell script to update SharePoint Online list items does not save all column values

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powershell-2.0, sharepoint-online, csom

I'm processing a CSV file to create SharePoint Online list items and save metadata as fields in its custom content type. At first, I thought it would be an issue related to column type, but I'm failing to save some simple text field values. What's puzzling is that I am able to save some but not other fields - even though I'm using the same means to do this - somehow the list item is not preserving all the values I send in for the list item update.

I create a new item with the following code:

```
$newFile = $targetfolderObj.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
$targetContext.Load($newFile)
$spContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Then I get the list item and start setting the field values

```
$newFileListItem = $newFile.ListItemAllFields

$newFileListItem.Properties["ColumnNameA"] = $_.CustomValue1 # saves
$newFileListItem.Properties["ColumnNameB"] = $_.CustomValue2 # not saving !!!
$newFileListItem.Properties["ColumnNameC"] = $_.CustomValue3 # saves
```

After setting up the properties with values I call the update and execute functions.

```
$newFileListItem.Update()
$spContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

*$*.CustomValue1 $*.CustomValue2* and *$_.CustomValue3* when printed all read as "Hello" for example, there are no special characters or symbols here - even hardcoding the field values to simple strings will fail to update field 2 but works on 1 and 3.

I am giving this example with my code to show it's not sequential - for example field 2 data is NOT saved but field 1 and 3 data is saved.

It always fails on the same columns, I verified the columns exist, I'm using the internal field names, string length is well within range, and there is no other validation applied on these columns. What could I possibly do to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging, I'm seeing SharePoint funnery at play...

while the content type is there, and the content type internal field name is "ColumnNameA" something must have gone sideways in the library instance, causing the column name to now be "ColumnNameA0" yes, a zero added at the end of the column name. Every column that was not updating had somehow now a "zero" at the end of the internal column name.

Solution 1: add the zero
Solution 2: recreate the library and re-associate it with the site conten type

I went with Solution 1 to test that my updates worked, then rebuilt the library.